# Has version 4.7 introduced an Activity Date filter problem with activity reports?

Tags: civireport

Since upgrading to 4.7 we have had the following problem:

Created a new Activity (contacts) report with
 - the Activity Date filter set to This week
 - the Navigation Menu Link To
   set to View Results

When running the report from the navigation menu the report is displayed without any filtering on Activity Date - the Activity Date filter has been reset to empty.

If I:

1. Set the (emptied) Activity Date filter to This week
2. Change the Navigation Menu Link To to Show Criteria
3. Click the Update Report button to save the changes
4. Re-run the report from the navigation menu

The report is not run, as expected, but the Activity Filter now remains set to This week. Clicking on the Preview Report button now produces the report I was expecting.

To see the problem on the demo site (while the Joomla demo site is still on 4.6):

[4.6](http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/report/instance/3&reset=1)

[4.7](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/3?reset=1)

Comment: this seems to be a bug with the update report, preview report works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with the update report, preview report works as expected. See guideline on bug reporting https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting